# Grails: groovy subcollection

Tags: grails, collections, groovy, closures, currying

Having the following domain class:

```
class Message{
}
```

Want to get all messages with `id` more than `offset`:

```
def offset = params.offset
def messages = Message.list()
def subMessages = messages.findAll({offset, it ->
    it.id > offset
}.curry(offset))
```

What's wrong?

---

**Upd**: i understand that `Message.list()` can be executed as `Message.list(params)` but it's not important now.

Comment: do you still have a question or you figure it out? Mark as closed please.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Example using a map

```
def params = [offset: 2]
def messages = [[id: 1], [id: 2], [id: 3], [id: 4], [id: 5]]
def subMessages = messages.findAll({ it.id > params.offset })
assert subMessages == [[id: 3], [id: 4], [id: 5]]
```

---

### Integration test using a Grails domain class

```
(1..5).each { new Message(text: "${it}").save(failOnError: true) }
def params = [offset: "2"]
def offset = Integer.parseInt(params.offset)
def messages = Message.list()
def subMessages = messages.findAll({ it.id > offset })
assert subMessages == Message.findAllByIdGreaterThan(offset)
```

Comment: Sorry, my fault. Your example works for maps, but not for domain classes.

Comment: @tiktak Actually it works fine for a Grails domain class `list` as well.

Comment: it's very strange. created an issue for it: http://jira.grails.org/browse/GRAILS-8730 Thanks for help.

Comment: The correct approach is to do the filtering in the database as this answer describes - pulling back every instance and filtering at the client is potentially very expensive. I've explained in the JIRA why your approach wasn't working.

Comment: Updated my answer to handle string to int conversion.